# How to keep the calling function thread on hold till the time all the threads processing gets completed?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpool, countdown

I am working on a scenario as described below:

- We are consuming messages from kafka, and each message received should be processed in parallel, given that I have to keep on hold the main( or calling) thread until all the messages received(1 message-1 thread) are done with processing.
  Given that number of messages is known and is available from the kafka message headers.
  Once the processing is completed for all the threads, only after that the calling thread should proceed ahead.

I tried using CountDownLatch with the count as number of messages going to be received, but using this, it is keeping the main thread on hold, and not allowing to consume the next messages.

Is there anyway, by which this can be achieved ?

Code Snippet:

```
class MessageHandler{

@Autowired private ProcessorAsync processorAsync;

public void handle()
{
   CountdownLatch countdown = new CountdownLatch(noOfMessages);
   CompletableFuture<Void> future = processorAsync.processMessage(message,countdown);
countdown.await();
if(future.isDone())
{//post msg processing methods/api calls
     m1();
     m2();
}
}
}
class ProcessorAsync
{
    @Async("customThreadPool") // max 20 threads
    public CompletableFuture<Void> processMessage(Message msg, CountdownLatch countdown)
{
  //DB update statements
  //  .

 countdown.countdown();
return CompletableFuture.allOf();
}
}
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @shmosel Added code snippet